# VBA Skipping Lines of Code

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a part of a macro that is being completely skipped when it is executing.  I think I probably has something to do with the if statement combined with the loop.

```
For x = 1 To HomeLoop
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet6.Range("G:G"), Sheets(1).Cells(x + 2, 1)) = 0 Then
        Sheets(1).Select
        Rows(x + 2).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Else
    End If
Next x
```

There is more code before and after the block.  When I'm going through the code with the debugger, the "For x = 1 to HomeLoop" will highlight and the next step goes directly to highlight the code below the "Next x"  I can't figure out why the block is being completely skipped.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: When the code stops on the For statement, hover over HomeLoop to see its value - it also helps everyone here if you show code before the problem code. Sometimes new eyes can see obvious errors

Comment: How are you setting the value of `HomeLoop`? Irregardless of the `IF` if should cycle through the loop. Making a guess perhaps `HomeLoop=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop basically runs an if statement each time it runs through

`for x = 1 to homeloop` is basically equivalent to  `if x<=homeloop`

my guess is homeloop doesn't have a value in it or is less then 1.  Do you have any sort of error handling in the code?